# How to rescale whole to scene including light radius to specified dimension?

Tags: transforms

I have a model for a big object - is it possible for me to tell Blender how big this model is, without having to go in and simply scaling the object up until it matches the right number of units? I've got a bunch of spot lights parented to it at certain scales and I found when I tried just scaling it up or down, things like the radius of the light wouldn't change with it.

So is there a way to tell Blender 'look at this model, this length is 312 m, now recalibrate yourself around that'?

Comment: Hey. I edited your title into a hopefully a lot clearer description of what you had. If you feel it is incorrect feel free to revert.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this natively, but sounds like something trivial to achieve with some simple Python scripting